# How to set xAxis in TIME type and formatted like {hh:mm} in Echarts?

Tags: echarts

I want to set xAxis in TIME type and formatted like {hh:mm} , such as 17:45.

In this [demo](http://echarts.baidu.com/demo.html#dynamic-data2), configuration works:

```
xAxis: {
    type: "time",
},

value: [
    [now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + 1, now.getDate()].join('/'),
    Math.round(value)
]
```

But this fails, here is [my demo](http://gallery.echartsjs.com/editor.html?c=xrk2YszEs&v=2) in Echarts gallery :

```
xAxis: {
    type: "time",
},

value: [
    [now.getHours(), now.getMinutes()].join(":"),
    Math.round(value)
]
```

I tried `type: "value"`, still not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `xAxis.axisLabel.formatter`. This can be a formatter string or a function.

Use this as reference:
https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.axisLabel.formatter

Answer (score 10):

As mention above you need to use xAxis.axisLabel.formatter.

Here is your example.

```
// Horizontal axis
xAxis: [{
    type: 'time', 
    axisLabel: {
      formatter: (function(value){
        let label;
        if (value.getMinutes() < 10){ 
          label = value.getHours() + ":0" +value.getMinutes();
        }
        else {
          label = value.getHours() + ":" +value.getMinutes();
        }
        return label;
      })
    }
}],
```

Answer (score 2):

I made your demo working.
I've changed the `value` like this:

```
value: [
    [now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + 1, now.getDate()].join('/') + 'T' +
    [now.getHours(), now.getMinutes()].join(':'),
    Math.round(value)
]
```

Please see this screenshot:

[image: Fixed image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for the answer, the link provided in the accepted answer is correct but has 404'd.

Here's the current working one: https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.axisLabel.formatter